# C bitarray set value

Tags: c, bit-shift

I am trying to speed up a program with bitshifts.
For doing that I am allocating some space for the bits to store.

Now I have to set the bit in the middle to 1.
So for example I want:

00000010000000

to be in my memory. (The length is defined by the user on run-time).

Here is my Code:

```
 int *state = malloc(b); // Where 'b' is a user defnied value
 *state |= (1 << b);
```

But when I print out the bits I get something like this (for b = 10):

000000000010000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000

So it keeps placing many 1's instead of one 1 in the middle.

What am I doing wrong here?

I belived it has to do with me using int, maybe the workaround would be not using int. But I don't know how to allocate a bitarray in another way.

This is how I print the bits (requestet in comments):

```
 64         for(i =0; i < b; i++){
 65                 printf("%d", ((*state & (1 << i)) >> i));
 66         }
```

Comment: *I am trying to speed up a program with bitshifts* - you must be desperate.

Comment: @Troubleshoot I think thats not his point, the reason is curiosity :)

Comment: Why not just `*state = (1 << b);`?

Comment: This can't be achived. malloc accept an argument to be the number of bytes not bits!

Comment: think you have got length defined by user on runtime part confued, malloc(b) give you b bytes not bits.

Comment: It runs with int arrays too, but why waste a 32bit int to store a bit. And yes, the main reason is, I want to try something different.

Comment: @user1203092 the minimum you can allocate is 1 byte

Comment: You didn't print the bits correctly.

Comment: you are clearly confusing bits and bytes.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: What is wrong with the print?

Comment: @user1203092 Wrong for `for(i =0; i < b; i++)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing up bits and bytes.

To allocate *b* bits, you need

```
int *state = malloc(sizeof(int)*((b+sizeof(int)-1)/sizeof(int))); // Where 'b' is a user defnied value
```

To set a bit in this array, decompose into *int* position and *bit* position:

```
state[b/sizeof(int)] |= (1 << (b % sizeof(int)));
```

If you are going to work with single bits, it might be easier to use `unsigned char` instead of `int` as the base array.

Edit: just changed the allocation from `(b+sizeof(int)-1)/sizeof(int)` -- this calculates the required *byte* size. Of course you need to allocate room for *int* sized members, so the allocated memory size is the number of *bytes* times `sizeof(int)`.